# Can't Mirror Database on Sql-Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mirroring

I'm running two MS-SQL instances to create a mirrored-database environment, I have an instance in a Virtual Machine and another instance, alongside the witness, in the physical machine. I know this isn't the best configuration but this is for learning purposes only.

Now, when I try to mirror the database it gives me the following error [image: this]. 
All the settings came automatically from the Mirror Configuration Wizard so the Server SHOULD be visible, besides I can connect to it from the physical management studio, and I have create an Inbound Rule on the VM to allow all incoming connections on port 5022.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using domain accounts for your SQL Server Service accounts? If not, what are you using? Local System? Are you using certificates?

This post is a good troubleshooter for some of the more common 1418 causes -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/grahamk/archive/2008/12/08/database-mirroring-error-1418-troubleshooter.aspx

In that blog there are a few links in the assumptions section that may apply here with your configuration.

Comment: I'm not using any domain... I am just on the same Workgroup (and Homegroup for what is worth) and I'm not implementing certificates...

Comment: what account is running your SQL Server Service on each instance?

Comment: `System` on all

Comment: Change it to Network service to see what happens. You'll have to restart the instances to make this change.

Comment: Got it... but my answer will have to wait till tonight when I get home :)

Comment: No luck... I also turned off the FILESTREAM option on both servers.